# Scalar valued function calling in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a function `dbo.fn_CreateJobID` which take string of `productType` and  returns `JobID` (string).

I called the function in query format.

```
var  JobID = dbContext.Database
               .SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("select dbo.fn_CreateJobID ('{0}')", productReceive.ProductType))
               .FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

But I want to call better way.

1. First `dbContext.` shows stored procedure but does not show function name ?
2. I have tried this 
   https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/

   but it shows error when I remove `ReturnType=""` parameter.

Please give me a suggestion proper way to call scalar valued function in EF 6.1?

Comment: Did you try "select * from dbo.fn_CreateJobID ('{0}')". You're not selecting any columns in your statement.

Comment: It works completely fine **select dbo.fn_CreateJobID ('{0}')**.But want to know the recommended way.

Comment: @DDiVita It's a scalar-valued function, not a table-valued function.